# Using 'caffe time' for benchmarking alexnet testing

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, intel-mkl

I am new to caffe and presently I am trying to use it with Alexnet. When I say use, I mean I don't want to train the network, therefore, I got the `'.caffemodel'` for Alexnet as mentioned [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/model_zoo.html).

Now, I want to use caffe's time feature to look at the time it takes for each layers execution during the TEST phase(I am doing for getting the execution time per layer during inference).

As per the caffe's options

```
usage: caffe <command> <args>

commands:
  train           train or finetune a model
  test            score a model
  ------------
  time            benchmark model execution time
  collect         collects layer data on specified device
  compare         collects layer data using inputs from other device

  Flags from tools/caffe.cpp:
      ---------------------
    -phase (Optional; network phase (TRAIN or TEST). Only used for 'time'.)
      type: string default: ""
    -sampling (Optional; Caffe test with sampling mode) type: bool
      default: false
     -------------------------
```

I can run the following command to benchmark Alexnet during TEST phase:

```
build/tools/caffe time -model models/bvlc_alexnet/train_val.prototxt -iterations 1000 -engine MKLDNN -phase TEST
```

But when I do that, I get the following error:

```
I0304 17:37:26.183619 29987 net.cpp:409] label_data_1_split does not need backward computation.
I0304 17:37:26.183625 29987 net.cpp:409] data does not need backward computation.
I0304 17:37:26.183629 29987 net.cpp:451] This network produces output accuracy
I0304 17:37:26.183635 29987 net.cpp:451] This network produces output loss
I0304 17:37:26.183647 29987 net.cpp:491] Network initialization done.
I0304 17:37:26.183732 29987 caffe.cpp:556] Performing Forward
I0304 17:37:26.287747 29987 caffe.cpp:561] Initial loss: 6.92452
I0304 17:37:26.287784 29987 caffe.cpp:563] Performing Backward
F0304 17:37:26.385227 29987 mkldnn_pooling_layer.cpp:464] Check failed: poolingBwd_pd 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fe03e3980cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fe03e399f33  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fe03e397c28  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fe03e39a999  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fe03ead741c  caffe::MKLDNNPoolingLayer<>::InitPoolingBwd()
    @     0x7fe03eac4ec2  caffe::MKLDNNPoolingLayer<>::Backward_cpu()
    @     0x7fe03e8f9b19  caffe::Net<>::Backward()
    @     0x5622d81a2530  (unknown)
    @     0x5622d8199353  (unknown)
    @     0x7fe03ab09b97  __libc_start_main
    @     0x5622d8198e1a  (unknown)
```

I am guessing there is some problem with the way I am using the command and I may have to change the `.prototxt` file for this.

I would appreciate if somebody can point me in the right direction as to how to get the benchmark numbers for Alexnet in Testing phase.

P.S: I could not find out what happens if you just run caffe time without specifying the Phase. Does it benchmark both the TEST and TRAIN phase?